# How can I change Database creation SQL script auto-generated by Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 for my database project, and using it to generate a Database_Create.sql script which I deploy and run against different servers.

There is some VisualStudio-generated code which needs to be manually edited which sets SQLCMD command variables for database name, default data and default log directories.

I can get the default data and default log directories programmatically in TSQL using SERVERPROPERYT('InstanceDefaultDataPath') but can't mix this with the SQLCMD commands.

I have a solution which I added manually to the Database_Create.sql script, but would like to bake it into the VS project and avoid a manual edit.

Can I change VisualStudio's code generation process so that the generated Database_Create.sql script will contain my code?

Specifically, the autogenerated code is :

```
Visual Studio generated a change script with the following lines:

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING --etc.;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;

GO
:setvar DatabaseName "Foo"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "Foo"
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""

GO
:on error exit
GO

:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END

GO
USE [master];

GO
PRINT N'Creating $(DatabaseName)...'
GO
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
GO
PRINT N'Creating [MediaFileGroup]...';

GO

ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILEGROUP [MediaFileGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM;

GO

ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE (NAME = [MediaFileGroup_12345678], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MediaFileGroup_12345678.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [MediaFileGroup];

GO
USE [$DataBaseName)];
```

I want to add a section of SQL code which will replace the

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE (NAME = [MediaFileGroup_12345678], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MediaFileGroup_12345678.mdf') TO FILEGROUP [MediaFileGroup];
```

(since this is the line that uses DefaultDataPath) so that my computed DefaultDataPath is used

My question is not about obtaining the Default Data Path programmatically - I can do that.  My question is : How can I change the VisualStudio-generated code section?